# How I can get another camera extrinsic parameters from first camera?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, camera, calibration

I try to do multi camera calibration.

In my situation ultimately I want to obtain second camera's extrinsic parameters or it's projection matrix from first camera's parameters (intrinsic and extrinsic).

I fix two cameras in rig and their distance and angle are also fixed. So I think I can find out their relationship and with this relation I can obtain second camera's parameters from the first one.

In real situation I install two cameras(fixed in rig) on the robot and in that situation I can't obtain all parameters. (I can obtain first camera's extrinsic parameters). So in this situation I want to do second camera calibration from first camera and their relation.

In the present I found first and second camera's distortion, intrinsic parameters and current extrinsic parameters. Of course extrinsic parameters are different with real situation. and I set their relation like this.

```
R_rel = R_2 * inv(R_1) ,  t_rel = -R_rel * t_1 + t_2
```

and I did

```
norimg_2 = R_rel * norimg_1 + t_rel  (norimg_1 = inv(intinsic_1) * img_1, norimg_2 = inv(intrinsic_2) * img_2
```

However I can't get right answer. I want to know if this relationship is wrong or this way is wrong.

- Of course,

  ```
  wld = [0, 0, 1];
  imgpoint_1 = K_n.' * extrin_1 * wld.';
  imgpoint_1_ = imgpoint_1/imgpoint_1(3);
  imgpoint_2 = K_f.' * extrin_2 * wld.';
  imgpoint_2_ = imgpoint_2/imgpoint_2(3);
  ```

like this I can get right answer. However I can't get extrinsic parameters `_2` in real situation so I'm very confused.

Comment: This is a question that's probably too specialized for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you work using a dichotomic approach, like in the [bisection approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

[image: Bisection approach]

You must try different values for parameters `_2` that you can't guess. Then little by little, you change the values inside a frame that reduces more and more. In the end you have calibration for camera 2 for camera 1.

This means you have a way to evaluate the inaccuracy of the result you get for given values of parameters `_2` .

If you don't find what you're looking for on SO, then you should also try https://photo.stackexchange.com/